# RegEx to Atlassian Jira Token Finder

Tags: regex, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm using Jmeter to test my Jira instance. I recorded a login and a Scrumboard action.

When I want to replicate this using 2000 users I am getting an error.
I know this is because of the Token in needs.

How can I create a regex for finding the token?

I am doing a request to the server that looks like this

```
GET httb://SOMESERVERON.intranet:8080/secure/Dashboard.jspa
```

Cookie Data:

```
JSESSIONID=#IDNUMBER; atlassian.xsrf.token=#TOKENNUMBER
```

> Request Headers: Connection: keep-alive Referer:
>   httb://SOMESERVERON.intranet:8080/plugins/servlet/gadgets/ifr?container=atlassian&mid=0&country=UK&lang=en&view=default&view-params=%7B%22writable%22%3A%22false%22%7D&st=atlassian%3AWYF9KCckTIxHKei%2BvMoCPKoa3LOkMGPilSEdaSqyqEFKIPnF0I3YcZDdKdElV0s%2B9%2FqBhMWhS2Qyvo7m0F2f3uTB3JBeKZF8Ou3EimeszE1Ms1IPMqDoYcVgPdF1CaQnnrANHwH1KhR1UxUlHed7VOyRPmfI26rO2FU65FQbvNuIZADHLRt1v8lF52vBeCqi6aSfyrfGau2lv3JDL4HVQv3dDmt%2FudFaX3a05CS94ncoGr0s&up_isPublicMode=false&up_isElevatedSecurityCheckShown=false&up_loginFailedByPermissions=false&up_externalUserManagement=false&up_loginSucceeded=false&up_allowCookies=true&up_externalPasswordManagement=&up_captchaFailure=false&up_isAdminFormOn=false&url=http%3A%2F%2Flrv142c3.europe.intranet%3A8080%2Frest%2Fgadgets%2F1.0%2Fg%2Fcom.atlassian.jira.gadgets%2Fgadgets%2Flogin.xml&libs=auth-refresh
>   Accept-Language: nl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3 Accept-Encoding: gzip,
>   deflate User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:34.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0 Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Host:
>   http://SOMESERVERON.intranet:8080

---

So I know to look for this part

```
name="atlassian-token" content="TOKENKEY"
```

But what is the RegEx that I need to find the token and put it in a parameter that I can re use.

Comment: Instead of request, paste the response content. Then we can provide you the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular Expression: `name="atlassian-token" content="(.+?)"`

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

For handling both `JSESSIONID` and `atlassian-token` cookies just add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar), JMeter is smart enough to deal with them automatically.

Comment: Thanks, for JSESSIONID HTTP Cookie Manager can handle it, but unfortunately the atlassioan-token can't. I will keep on trying.